# It shows 405 Server error at first time to get result from API server, and it works fine at second time

Tags: swift, alamofire

It shows 405 Server error at first time to get result from API server, and it works fine at second time. I've been trying to solve this issue for a month and couldn't find the solution.

I used Xcode 9.2, Swift 4, and Alamofire 4.6.

Main problem - API server logs suppose to show "POST" on http method. Howerver it shows only "ST" on http method. (This is the main problem.) This caused to get 405 server error.

My Source Codes using Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post  , parameters: [“phone”:”123123”],encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
  .validate()
  .responseJSON { (response) in
  if response.result.isSuccess {
    success(response.result.value as! Dictionary)
 } else {
 LogHelper.printLog("response : \(response)")

    fail(response.result.error)
 }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

- I added "application/json" on header => nothing changed.
- I changed Alamofire versions and reinstalled it. => nothing changed.
- Parameter Key change => 405 error and 500 error
- Parameter value change => 405 error at first time, and success at second time request.
- Alamofire econding change => nothing changed.
- remove ".validate()" on Alamofire request. => nothing changed.
- change to responseString from responseJSON => nothing changed.

Comment: What's the URL you're using?  Have you tried running your app through Charles or something similar?  https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: you shoul change this [“phone”:”123123”] to ["phone":"123123"]

Comment: @Malleswari same error..

Answer (score 0):

The current behaviour, where NSURLSession sends the Content-Length header but not the message body.

check this link: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/2887